# I need to assign a query result to a variable in Oracle stored procedure variable, where my table in from clause is another query?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to assign a query result to a variable in Oracle stored procedure, where my table in from clause is another query?

For e.g.

```
Select employee_name into v_employee_name 
where (select emp_name from emp e,dept d 
       where d.emp_id=e.emp_id and d.dept_id=e.dept_id and emp_id ='123')
```

I do not have permissions to create a temporary table in DB.

Comment: And what is your problem? You can do this in procedure, you need only permission to select.

Comment: The `WHERE`  clause is ill formed. It is not clear to me _what_ you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like the below,

```
Select employee_name into v_employee_name 
from (select emp_name from emp e,dept d 
       where d.emp_id=e.emp_id and d.dept_id=e.dept_id and emp_id ='123');
```

and make sure your inner query returns one value if your v_employee_name is just a plain varchar2, else you would get an exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows error.

Comment: What is the purpose of the nested query here ?

Comment: It's useless, just showing him how to do this as per his question. I understand what you're asking though :)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, your query might simply be written as:

```
select emp_name into v_employee_name
from emp e,dept d 
       where d.emp_id=e.emp_id and d.dept_id=e.dept_id and d.emp_id ='123'
```

And if you are open to the "modern" (i.e.: post SQL-92) join syntax:

```
select emp_name into v_employee_name
from emp e join dept d
using(emp_id,dept_id)
where emp_id ='123'
```